# How to hardcode smart contract address in minting policy in Plutus?

Tags: plutus

1st way I tried to do it was to get validator address using this function:

```
{-# INLINABLE scriptAddress #-}
-- | The address that should be used by a transaction output locked by the given validator script.
scriptAddress :: Validator -> Address
scriptAddress validator = Address (ScriptCredential (validatorHash validator)) Nothing
```

For example:

```
-- | The validator script of the game.
gameValidator :: ValidatorScript
gameValidator =
    ValidatorScript ($$(Ledger.compileScript [|| validateGuess ||]))

gameAddress :: Address
gameAddress = Ledger.scriptAddress gameValidator
```

Then use this gameAddress variable as parameter in minting policy, which compiles and works fine.

But real contract address never matches the address parameter, script fails on cardano-cli submit:

```
txOutputs :: [TxOut]
txOutputs = txInfoOutputs info

ownOutput :: TxOut
ownOutput = case [o | o <- txOutputs, gameAddress == txOutAddress o] of
[o] -> o
_ -> error ()
```

We always get an error here (I am sure that there is an output to the same smart contract).

This gameAddress has no awareness of mainnet/testnet, maybe that's the reason why it does not match? Maybe there is a way to fix this?

Also, is there a way to simply hardcode smart contract address into Plutus code? Like we can do with PubKeyHash?:

```
hardcodedPubKeyHash :: PubKeyHash
hardcodedPubKeyHash = "f1befc070bbc16ea613cfc0f0a5c0f856063f1ecbe640556136568f8"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it does not match, it means your off-chain code is using a different address than what you expect on-chain.

An address is comprised of two parts, the payment and the staking part. You seem to be calculating the address of the payment part being the `ValidatorHash` of your game script and the staking part to be `Nothing`.

Maybe your off-chain code is creating the address slightly differently?

There is a function `scriptOutputsAt` in V1/V2 `plutus` (https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/5cc518f1202930ad52b8ba838af32af084c0e754/plutus-ledger-api/src/Plutus/V1/Ledger/Contexts.hs#L251-L258) which you could also use. It explicitly only looks at the payment part and ignores the staking part.

Comment: good point. managed to make it working using scriptOutputsAt function. Nothing else worked, even extracting ValidatorHash from each output and comparing it to ValidatorHash parameter from contract (gameValidatorHash = validatorHash $ Validator $ mkGameScript). Thanks!

Comment: If it worked, you can accept the answer (I guess there is a button for that).

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell `"f1befc070bbc16ea613cfc0f0a5c0f856063f1ecbe640556136568f8"` is a string (because its enclosed in double quotes), not a `PubKeyHash`.

I think all you need to add the constructor like this (it compiles, but not 100% sure it does the right thing):

```
hardcodedPubKeyHash :: PubKeyHash
hardcodedPubKeyHash = PubKeyHash "f1befc070bbc16ea613cfc0f0a5c0f856063f1ecbe640556136568f8"
```